# How does remove() function work in this code?

Tags: c++, function

I am learning C++ and came across the `struct Link {};` code on pages 465 and 466 of "The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition" by Bjarne Stroustrup. Here is that code, with some helpful info (addresses) printed for my understanding as the code gets executed.

```
include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Link {
    Link* prev;
    Link* next;
    int data;
    Link* insert(int x) {
        prev = new Link{prev, this, x};
        cout << "address of new prev:" << prev << endl;
        cout << "address of new prev->prev:" << prev->prev << endl;
        cout << "address of new prev->next:" << prev->next << endl;
        cout << "prev->data :" << prev->data << endl;
        cout << "address of this:" << this << endl;
        return prev;
    }

    void remove() {
        cout << "\n\nRemoving elements!" << endl;        
        if (prev) {
            cout << "Removing data:" << prev->data << endl;
            cout << "Before prev:" << prev << " " << "prev->next:" << prev->next << endl;
            prev->next = next;
            cout << "After prev:" << prev << " " << "prev->next:" << prev->next << endl;
        }
        if (next) {
            cout << "Removing data:" << next->data << endl;
            next->prev = prev;
            cout << "next:" << next << " " << "next->prev:" << next->prev << endl;
        }
        delete this;
    }

    void print() {
        Link* temp = prev;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            cout << "temp->data:" << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Link* x {new Link};
    cout << "Address of x:" << x << endl;
    x->prev = nullptr;
    x->next = nullptr;
    cout << "\n\nInserting:2"<< endl;
    x->insert(2);
    cout << "\n\nInserting:4"<< endl;
    x->insert(4);
    cout << "\n\nInserting:5"<< endl;
    x->insert(5);
    x->remove();
    return 0;
}
```

I am having difficulty understanding how the `remove()` function works in removing and destroying `this`.

From the `remove()` function, I see that it does not systematically destroy the list, but instead simply sets `prev->next` to `next`, where `next` is `0x0`. Is this the right understanding? If it is, then I see that memory used up for `2` and `4` is not freed. Would that not be a memory leak?

Comment: Simply step through your code line by line with the debugger to see what's going on, what's the problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there is nothing wrong with it in this case. Self-destroying objects are legal

Comment: `remove` removes the _current_ link, nothing more (i.e. `this`).

Comment: I f I run this code in the debugger, I see it simply removes the value **5** and sets **prev->next to next**.  But since **next** is **0x0**, it simply executes **delete this**. I thought removing element by element and then finally destroying the object is the right way, but it seems it does not have to be so and we can just delete the object though not all elements are removed systematically. Not sure why this question was downvoted though.

Comment: @user3602207 see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

`remove()` is unlinking the node it is called on, by updating its neighboring nodes to point at each other instead of the removed node. Then `delete this` is destroying the removed node so it is not leaked.

However, this code is calling `remove()` on just 1 of the 4 nodes being created. So the other 3 nodes are being leaked.

Calling `remove()` on the 1st node in a list will not update the caller's pointer to that node, which can lead to problems, if you still need to access the remaining list at a later time, or if you are removing nodes while iterating the list, etc. It would be a good idea to have `remove()` return the `next` node in the list so the caller can continue from that node if needed.

Calling `insert()` adds a new node *in front of* the node it is called on.  After the 4 nodes are created, `x` is pointing at the *last* node in the list. That is why the node's `next` is null. After `x->remove()` is called, you lose your pointer to the entire remaining list. It would be a good idea to have `insert()` return the new node created so the caller can update their "head" pointer if needed. Otherwise, `insert()` should be changed to add the new node *after* the node it is called on.